# ¿Cómo pasar datos de una scene de JavaFX a otra mediante un ArrayList<>?

Tags: java, poo, javafx, javafx11

¿Cómo paso los datos guardados en una scene a otra?

Mi programa es un login básico, con pantallas una detrás de otra para dar de alta alumnos, darles de baja y consultar la lista de alumnos. Lo que intento hacer es almacenar los datos de los alumnos (nombre, apellido, dni) en alta alumnos y que en las otras dos (*bajaAlumnos* y *consulta*) pueda darles de baja y consultarlo.

Sé como manejar `ArrayList<>`, lo que no sé es cómo plantear las conexiones entre scenes. Por ahora tengo esto en el controlador de *AltaAlumnos*:

```
package com.loginjfx.loginjfx;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.*;

public class AltaCtrl {
    @FXML
    private Button btnAceptar;

    @FXML
    private Button btnCancelar;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtDNI;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtLastName;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtName;

    ArrayList<Data> alumnos = new ArrayList<>();
    @FXML
    void OnClickAceptar(ActionEvent event) {
        String nombre = txtName.getText();
        String apellido = txtLastName.getText();
        String DNI = txtDNI.getText();

        //Se supone que aqui tienen que guardarse los datos de alguna forma

        Data new_alumno = new Data();
        new_alumno.setNombre(nombre);
        new_alumno.setApellido(apellido);
        new_alumno.setDNI(DNI);
        alumnos.add(new_alumno);

    }

    @FXML
    void OnClickCancelar(ActionEvent event) {
        Stage stagePrincipal = (Stage) btnCancelar.getScene().getWindow();
        stagePrincipal.close();
    }
    public ArrayList<Data> DevuelveLista(){

        return alumnos;
    }
}
```

Mi profesor me recomendó hacer un método al final de este controlador para que devolviese los datos de "alumnos", pero cuando llego a *bajaAlumnos*:

```
package com.loginjfx.loginjfx;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.*;

public class BajaCtrl {
    @FXML
    private Button btnDeny;

    @FXML
    private Button btnOK;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtDNI;

    @FXML
    void OnClickDeny(ActionEvent event) {
        Stage stagePrincipal = (Stage) btnDeny.getScene().getWindow();
        stagePrincipal.close();
    }

    @FXML
    void OnClickOK(ActionEvent event) {
        String DNI = txtDNI.getText();

    }
}
```

O a *consultaAlumnos*:

```
package com.loginjfx.loginjfx;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

import java.util.*;

public class ConsultaCtrl {
    @FXML
    private Button btnConsultar;

    @FXML
    private TextArea txtConsulta;

    @FXML
    void OnClickConsultar(ActionEvent event) {
        txtConsulta.setText("");
    }
}
```

No sé por dónde cogerlo. ¿Con qué métodos manejar estos datos? ¿Debería crear otra clase? (Tengo una clase *Data* para guardar nombre, apellidos y dni con getters y setters.)

Comment: la instancia del controlador se obtiene con FXMLLoader.getcontroller() . Una vez obtenida se puede pasar datos . Una cosa . Para qué llama Stage.close()  si va a abrir otra stage . eso no tiene ningún sentido